# Establish connection string with local database in .NET Core and EF Core

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a project in .NET Core 6 with EF Core. I need to do some tests with a local database that does not have a password, I have tried many ways to set the connection string in my `appsetting.json` file but I always get the same error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

My local db:

[image]

These are the different ways I have tried in the `appsetting.json` file

```
connectionStrings": {
    "test1": "Server=LAPTOP-IJEET9LJ\\pcname;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;", //not work
    "test2": "Server=localhost;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;", ////not work
    "test3": "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;", ////not work
    "test4": "Server=LAPTOP-IJEET9LJ\\pcname;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" ////not work}
```

I have looked for several solutions but I cannot find the valid connection format for a local database that does not have a password, any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried including `tcp:` in the connection string to force use of the TCP/IP client driver instead of Named Pipes? e.g.: `"Server=tcp:yourServerName\\yourInstanceName;..."`